# Holomorphic Functions w/ the Same Partial Derivative w.r.t. z Differ by a Constant

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Apologies if this is a trivial result - I'm trying to prove the following: If $F,G,H$ are holomorphic on some open connected set $U \subset \mathbb{C}$, and
$$ \frac{\partial G}{\partial z} = F = \frac{\partial H}{\partial z} $$
then $G$ and $H$ differ by a constant.

It seems that these hypotheses are meant to imply that
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial \bar z} \bigg(\frac{\partial G}{\partial z} \bigg) = \frac{\partial }{\partial \bar z} \bigg(\frac{\partial H}{\partial z} \bigg) = 0$$
i.e. the partials with respect to $z$ of $G$ and $H$ are holomorphic as well, but that doesn't seem to get me any closer to obtaining the conclusion. Is this the right approach, or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f(z) := G-H$ and write $f(z) = u(z)+\mathrm{i} v(z)$, then
$$0=f'(z) = u_x(z) + i v_x(z).$$
Thus $u_x \equiv 0$ and also $v_x \equiv 0$. Using the Cauchy–Riemann equations, i.e. $u_x = v_y$ and $u_y = - v_x$ we also conclude that $v_y \equiv 0$ and $u_y \equiv 0$. Hence $Df(z) =0$, where $Df$ is the classic derivate in $\mathbb{R}^2$. This implies that $f$ is constant.